# Visual Studio 2008 Professional missing build action property

Tags: visual-studio-2008, parameters, certificate, embed

I'm following [this](http://www.spikezilla-software.com/blog/?p=24) tutorial on how to embed a certificate. At a certain point i have to do this action:

"Assuming you already have your certificate saved to a file (i’ve tested this with a .cer and a .pfx file), just add it to your project. Then click once on the file, and in the Properties window, set the Build Action to Embedded Resource."

But on my properties windows the **Build Action** parameters is missing.

More info:
- It's a Visual C++ project.

Anyone know why i don't have this parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DropTheAction: The 1) section ( mistakenly ) assumes the users knows how to add the certificate to the project. The very first step after the saving the .pfx or .cer file is right click on your project, "*Add*" > "*Existing item...*" > browse to the file you saved. Make sure in your windows dialog you've selected the "*All Files (*)*" option from the right bottom combo box so you will be able to see all the files ( by default, only "*Visual C# files*" will come up ).

Once you have added the file, just right click on the "*Properties*" option. The Properties windows including the Build Action.

BTW - Double check your Properties windows is selected to be displayed on your workspace ("*View*" menu -> "*Properties Window*" option ).

Hope those setps helps!

Comment: I did what you say but there is no property called Build Action.